Implement spoilers with the details and summary elements
Seven years ago, I pointed out that Spoilers are inaccessible to keyboard-only users. Four years later, I suggested an alternative solution that is natively accessible, namely using the details and summary elements. I am now posting this as a feature request.
Implementing spoilers with the details and summary elements has several advantages over the current one:

It is natively keyboard accessible. (details and summary are well supported by browsers, with the exceptions of Internet Explorer 11 (or older) and Opera Mini, but it seems SE does not support those browsers anyway.)
It uses elements that are semantically appropriate for disclosures, whereas the blockquote element, which is currently in use, is not.
It is well supported by screen readers with the exception of VoiceOver on iOS (based on data from 2022).
It does not need CSS-generated content such as s-prose .spoiler::after { ...; content: attr(data-spoiler) " "; ...; background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' aria-hidden='true' fill='rgb(132, 141, 149)' width='18' height='18' viewBox='0 0 18 18'%3E%3Cpath d='M9 17A8 8 0 119 1a8 8 0 010 16zM8 4v6h2V4H8zm0 8v2h2v-2H8z'%3E%3C/path%3E%3C/svg%3E"); } (to display the text "Reveal spoiler" and the exclamation point) in the current implementation.
It doesn't need JavaScript event listeners to open because the browser takes care of that.
It allows the spoiler to be closed again, which is not possible in the current implementation without reloading the page.

In summary, the advantages boil down to two main things:

Better accessibility, particularly for keyboard-only users. (This group is not limited to blind persons but includes various types of motor impairments that make using a mouse difficult or impossible.)
Much simpler code from a web developer's point of view.

